# List of points with colors

Tags: plotting

I am working with a list of points on the plane, to each of them a natural number is assigned. It will be responsinble for the points' colors.

1) My first question is very easy: at initial moment I create list of random points and assign number 1 to all of them. I am doing this, probably, too ugly:

```
listOfPoints = RandomReal[{0,10}, {1000, 2}];
listOfPoints = Map[Append[#, 1] &, listOfPoints];
ListPlot[Map[Take[#, 2] &, listOfPoints]]
```

(Here colors still does not play.) Does exist a more elegant way?

2) And after I make some manipulations with some elements of the list, each manipulation will increase the number assigned to the element, i.e. its last coordinate. And then I would like to produce ListPlot in such a way that the color of a point {x,y,n} from the list will be, say,

```
Blend[{{Blue}, {Red}}, 1/n]
```

How do realize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is better to store coordinates (real numbers) and integer numbers separately. You will benefit from [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/4678)

```
n = 1000;
points = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {n, 2}];
numbers = ConstantArray[1, n];
```

After some data monipulation you will have different numbers. You can plot them easily with `Point` with specified `VertexColors`

```
numbers = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n];

Graphics[Point[points, VertexColors -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, 1/#] & /@ numbers)], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
listOfPoints = MapIndexed[Join[#1, #2] &, RandomReal[{0, 10}, {1000, 2}]];
Graphics[{Blend[{Blue, Red}, 1/#3], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ listOfPoints, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the blending very quickly results in basically all `Blue` (you can see the first point in red in the upper right). The problem is illustrated here:

```
Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] & /@ Table[1/n, {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

You might want to choose a different function to get a smoother transition from `Red` to `Blue`. Perhaps a linear interpolation:

```
listOfPoints = MapIndexed[Join[#1, #2] &, RandomReal[{0, 10}, {1000, 2}]];
Graphics[{Blend[{Blue, Red}, (1000 - #3 + 1)/1000], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ listOfPoints, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

---

(I like `MapIndexed`, due to its flexibility: you can actually put the function directly in there as, for instance,

```
listOfPoints = MapIndexed[Join[#1, 1/#2] &, RandomReal[{0, 10}, {1000, 2}]];
```

but of course you can always do just

```
listOfPoints = Transpose@Join[Transpose@#, {Range[Length@#]}] &@ RandomReal[{0, 10}, {1000, 2}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider to use `ListPointPlot3D` for this kind of problem

```
points = 10;
colors = 3;

data =
  Join[
   RandomReal[{0, 10}, {points, 2}],
   List /@ RandomInteger[{1, colors}, points],
   2];

data // TableForm
```

[image]

```
plot =
 ListPointPlot3D[
  data, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize @ Large,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

If you want you can use `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Blue}, #3] &)`

Let it look like a `ListPlot`

```
Show[
 plot,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 Axes -> {True, True, False},
 Boxed -> False,
 FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

Compare

```
ListPlot[Most /@ data, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

View it from front

```
Show[
 plot,
 Axes -> {False, True, True},
 Boxed -> False,
 FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
 ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}]
```

[image]